# Unable to get the characters run time error vba

Tags: vba, excel

This code had been working but I'm unsure why vba can't seem to get past this line anymore. I get the Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the characters property of the Range class. Any help is appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub proj()
    Dim dataRng As range, cl As range
    Dim arr As Variant

    Set dataRng = Worksheets("ItalicSourceSheet").range("C1:C5") '<--| change "ItalicSourceSheet" with your actual source sheet name
    With Worksheets("ItalicOutputSheet") '<--|change "ItalicOutputSheet" with your actual output sheet name
        For Each cl In dataRng
            arr = GetItalics(cl) '<--| get array with italic words
            If IsArray(arr) Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arr) '<--| if array is filled then write it down to output sheet first blank cell in column "A"
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function GetItalics(rng As range) As Variant
    Dim strng As String
    Dim iEnd As Long, iIni As Long, strngLen As Long

    strngLen = Len(rng.Value2)
    iIni = 1
    Do While iEnd <= strngLen
        Do While rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Italic And rng.Characters(iEnd, 1).Font.Underline
            If iEnd = strngLen Then Exit Do
            iEnd = iEnd + 1
        Loop
        If iEnd > iIni Then strng = strng & Mid(rng.Value2, iIni, iEnd - iIni) & "|"
        iEnd = iEnd + 1
        iIni = iEnd
    Loop
    If strng <> "" Then GetItalics = Split(Left(strng, Len(strng) - 1), "|")
End Function​
```

Comment: Are you using an older version of excel?

Comment: I'm using 2013. It had been working but all of a sudden today its throwing an error on this line.

Comment: What cells and worksheet make up the `rng` object?

Comment: And what is `iEnd`? Maybe it would help to see more of your code.

Comment: Does some of the data over which you are iterating have errors?

Comment: The data does not have errors and ive uploaded the function that has the issue

Comment: `iEnd` doesn't have an initial value.

Comment: As @MattCremeens stated iEnd must be assigned a starting value of 1 `iEnd = 1` before the loop.

Comment: Does rng contain a formula instead of a constant value?

Comment: I added the full code and when I try iEnd having an initial value it crashes

Comment: I can't replicate with test data.  What's in ItalicSourceSheet!C1:C5?

Comment: randomly started working again thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

I guess that ItalicSourceSheet!C1:C5 contains formulas (calculated values) and the Characters property is not available therefore. In this case you should check if the whole cell is italic (parts of it cannot be) or skip these cells (depending on the business logic).